# Are programming-game questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I've been trying out an AI programming game lately.  It's not really game development per se, but it is AI programming.  It also happens to be a difficult topic to search for, having only the terms "programming" and "game" to go on.  I could see it being *mostly* acceptable to post about it on a lot of SE sites.

So what do think, would a question about how to solve a problem for a programming game be acceptable here?  I can't think of an answer other than case-by-case.

**Edit:**
A question has appeared in the wild.  It's the game I was thinking of, to boot.
[Drone targeting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54350/drone-targeting)

Comment: Do you have an example of the type of question you would ask?

Comment: No.  :|

I guess I meant a coding question, but scoped to the context of the language or script or whatever of that subject game.  If it was framed as an AI question, that would make it easier to accept.

Answer (score 3):

The main site faq has a pretty good rule of thumb.

> Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?

Depending on the question, use that to determine whether or not it's on topic for here or SO.